# log4j : logging for my java file server logs are also coming to file

Tags: java, log4j

According to my logger-log4j.properties file :

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, TestLogger
log4j.appender.TestLogger=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.TestLogger.File=TestLogger.log
log4j.appender.TestLogger.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.TestLogger.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.TestLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TestLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t]- %p
log4j.category.org.apache=DEBUG
```

When my class is getting executed, after execution i am getting serverlog also. How to stop the logging from server. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why did you not use the default SO font?  Making your question bigger does not get you more and faster answers.

Comment: i have already edited the question and it is waiting for approval

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the first line:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, TestLogger
```

Now instead of setting the root to `DEBUG`, just set it to `ERROR` and then set the Logging level of the catagory that you want to `DEBUG` only.

I think you should right something like this `log4j.category.com.mypackage.MyClass=DEBUG`

Here the com.mypackage.MyClass should be your fully qualified class name as expected to be in your file

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where i should set to DEBUG

Comment: do you have any log statements in your java file? just post them and I will do the needful

Comment: TestLogger.debug(_className, methodName,": Constructor Entering ");

Comment: I think you should right something like this `log4j.category.com.mypackage.MyClass=DEBUG` if you know what I mean....

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the additivity option of log4j.

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-additivity-what-and-why/